# Convert Jsp response into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, jsp

I have an issue as i am trying to retrieve data from jsp in angularjs. Is it feasible? If not.. what are other ways to get retrieve data in angular js controller. Can anyone else help me out to get solution.  My Code is given below....

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module("myApp", []).controller('testController',['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log)
     {
                var stateNameHindi = "";
                var stateLandingPageUrl = "";
        $scope.ScopeObject = {
              states : [

             { name: "राज्य चुनें", Ename: "select", district: [{Hnname: 'जिला चुनें', DEname: "Select" }] },
             { name: "राजस्थान ", Ename: "Rajasthan", district: [{  Hnname: 'जयपुर' , DEname: "jaipur"}] },
             { name: "छत्तीस गढ़ ", Ename: "Chattisgarh", district: [{  Hnname: 'बिलास पुर', DEname: "Bilaspur"}, {  Hnname: 'रायपुर', DEname: "raipur"}] },
             { name: "गुजरात ",  Ename: "Gujrat", district: [ {  Hnname: 'अहमदाबाद', DEname: "Ahmdabad"}, {  Hnname: 'सूरत', DEname: "surat"}, {  Hnname: 'वड़ोदरा', DEname: "vadodra"} ] }

             ],

            } ;

        $scope.selectAction = function(EngStateName, EngCityName ) {
            var state = EngStateName.Ename;
            var city = EngCityName.DEname;

            $scope.CityData = $http.get('/xyz/CityNews.jsp', 
            {
                params:{state: state, city: city}})
            .then(function(response)
                    {
                     if (response.status == 200){
                alert("mayank");
                        $scope.CityData = JSON.parse(response);
                        alert("sing" + $scope.CityData);

                        $log.info(response);}
                    }, function myError(response) {
                        $scope.CityData  = response.statusText;
         });
        };    

       $scope.StateSelect = function(EngStateName) {
            var state = EngStateName.Ename;

            $scope.StateData = $http.get('/xyz/CityNews.jsp', 
            {
                params:{state: state}})
            .then(function(response)
                    {
                     if (response.status == 200){
                alert("mayank");
                        $scope.StateData =  JSON.stringify(response);
                        var data = JSON.parse($scope.CityData)
                        alert("sing" + data);
                        $log.info(response);}
                    }, function myError(response) {
                        $scope.CityData  = response.statusText;
         });
        };   

     }]);



 </script>



 <div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="testController">
        <select name="state"  ng-options="c.name for c in ScopeObject.states track by c.Ename" ng-model="ScopeObject.SelectedData" ng-change="StateSelect(ScopeObject.SelectedData)">
        <option value=''>राज्य चुनें</option>

        </select>
       <select district="cityname"  ng-options="d.Hnname for d in ScopeObject.SelectedData.district track by d.DEname" ng-model="ScopeObject.cityname" ng-change="selectAction(ScopeObject.SelectedData, ScopeObject.cityname )">
        <option value=''>जिला चुनें</option>
       </select>
        <p>  {{CityData}}   </p>
        <p>  {{StateData}}  </p> 
    </div>


 </div>
```

Comment: Not at all clear what your specific problem is.

Comment: I have written our logic in CityNews.jsp and want to get its response as per   change of dropdown. But I am getting null as response. So my concern is that whether we can get response of jsp in angularjs directly or we need to convert jsp response in json....Actually i am unable to get jsp response. So how i can access jsp directly in angularjs. hope now you will understand mu concern.

Comment: it makes no difference to  angular what server technology you are using. Browsers have no way to know and nor do they care